WriteOnGrid package -- package options produce unexpected errors
I encounter strange errors when I try to use the WriteOnGrid package. MWE follows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{WriteOnGrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{EnvGrid}[NumSquares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
\end{EnvGrid}
\end{document}

The package documentation says that the option NumSquares=Auto should produce a full page of the Séyès grid, but instead I get errors like Missing number: treated as zero and Package PGF math error: unknown function 'Auto'... By the same token, the documentation indicates that NumSquares=20xL should fill the remaining vertical space with a grid 20 columns wide, but instead I get similar errors to the above. However, if I put in two definite values, as in NumSquares=18x5, I get the grid I'm asking for. It's only the variable grid dimensions that seem to greate problems.
What's going on here and how can I fix it?
Update: log file
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.11.22)  10 DEC 2024 21:42
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**seyes_experiment_2.tex
(./seyes_experiment_2.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/writeongrid/WriteOnGrid.sty
Package: WriteOnGrid 2023/11/15 v0.1.5 package to write on grid lines

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks17
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen141
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen142
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
Package: pgf 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen143
\Gin@req@width=\dimen144
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks19
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks20

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfil
tered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks21
))
\pgf@x=\dimen145
\pgf@y=\dimen146
\pgf@xa=\dimen147
\pgf@ya=\dimen148
\pgf@xb=\dimen149
\pgf@yb=\dimen150
\pgf@xc=\dimen151
\pgf@yc=\dimen152
\pgf@xd=\dimen153
\pgf@yd=\dimen154
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count196
\c@pgf@countb=\count197
\c@pgf@countc=\count198
\c@pgf@countd=\count199
\t@pgf@toka=\toks22
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks23
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks24
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count266

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count267
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count268
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 274.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen155
\pgfmath@count=\count269
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks25
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks26
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks27
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count270
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen156
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen157
\pgf@picminy=\dimen158
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen159
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen160
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen161
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen162
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen163
\pgf@xx=\dimen164
\pgf@xy=\dimen165
\pgf@yx=\dimen166
\pgf@yy=\dimen167
\pgf@zx=\dimen168
\pgf@zy=\dimen169
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen170
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen171
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen172
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen173
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfpic=\box53
\pgf@hbox=\box54
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box55
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count271
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen174
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen175
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen176
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen177
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen178
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@max=\dimen179
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count272
\pgf@shadingcount=\count273
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box56
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.
tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box57
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen180
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen181
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen182
\pgffor@skip=\dimen183
\pgffor@stack=\toks28
\pgffor@toks=\toks29
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
Package: tikz 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count274
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen184
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen185
\tikz@lasty=\dimen186
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen187
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen188
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen189
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen190
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen191
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen192
\tikz@figbox=\box58
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box59
\tikz@tempbox=\box60
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box61
\tikztreelevel=\count275
\tikznumberofchildren=\count276
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count277
\tikz@fig@count=\count278

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count279
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count280
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count281
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count282

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/simplekv/simplekv.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/simplekv/simplekv.tex)
Package: simplekv 2023/10/02 v0.2c Simple keyval package (CT)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\xs_counta=\count283
\xs_countb=\count284
)
Package: xstring 2023/08/22 v1.86 String manipulations (CT)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
\c@lgquadri=\count285

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty
Package: setspace 2022/12/04 v6.7b set line spacing
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-02-20 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count286
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box62
)
(./seyes_experiment_2.aux)
\openout1 = `seyes_experiment_2.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count287
\scratchdimen=\dimen193
\scratchbox=\box63
\nofMPsegments=\count288
\nofMParguments=\count289
\everyMPshowfont=\toks30
\MPscratchCnt=\count290
\MPscratchDim=\dimen194
\MPnumerator=\count291
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count292
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks31
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))

! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `Auto' (in '0.8*Auto').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...Squares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
                                                  
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.7 ...Squares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `Auto' (in '0.8*Auto').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...Squares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
                                                  
(That was another \errmessage.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.7 ...Squares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `Auto' (in '0.8*Auto+0.8*0').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...Squares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
                                                  
(That was another \errmessage.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.7 ...Squares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `Auto' (in '0.8*Auto+0.8*0').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...Squares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
                                                  
(That was another \errmessage.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.7 ...Squares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `Auto' (in '0.8*Auto+0.8*0').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...Squares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
                                                  
(That was another \errmessage.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.7 ...Squares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `Auto' (in '0.8*Auto+0.8*0').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...Squares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
                                                  
(That was another \errmessage.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.7 ...Squares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.7 ...Squares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.7 ...Squares=Auto,Grid=Seyes]<black!66/black!33>
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./seyes_experiment_2.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 12590 strings out of 474116
 263570 string characters out of 5743681
 1926187 words of memory out of 5000000
 34760 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 117i,5n,121p,432b,541s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>

Output written on seyes_experiment_2.pdf (1 page, 9210 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 13 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)


can you post the complete log? I can't reproduce that error. also, which engine are you using? I tried pdftex, luatex and xetex and they all compile without error. I don't say they compile correctly, mind, but they do compile.

Posted. See what you think.

You're using an old version of WriteOnGrid. Update your distribution

From the manual:

History
v0.1.8: Styles for rules thickness
v0.1.7: New feature for french paper PleinePageCinqCinq
v0.1.6: Possibility to automatically determine L&C based on the
remaining space.
v0.1.4: ...

From your log:
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/writeongrid/WriteOnGrid.sty
Package: WriteOnGrid 2023/11/15 v0.1.5 package to write on grid lines

So we see that you have only version 0.1.5, while automatic space-filling was introduced in version 0.1.6.
This is one reason I think it is worth installing the doc tree even if you have perfectly reliable internet access. In that way, you are guaranteed1 to get documentation for the versions of packages etc. you have installed.
1Provided a few trivial conditions are fulfilled, such as the perfect reliability of all package and format authors, CTAN maintainers, TeX Live maintainers, your local mirror, your Linux distro/homebrew/macports/BSD equivalent texlive packager (if applicable), your DNS provider and yourself. Warranty void where prohibited. Warranty void where permitted. Other terms and conditions may apply. Existing users not eligible. By reading this footnote, you agree to all past, present and future provisions of an obscure legal entity. Copy of such provisions available on request in an ancient Runic script on payment of a small ransom and triplicate notorised copies of your great-great-great-great-grandmother's signature.
